# jQuery position().left always === 0 after animating marginLeft '-=300px'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, position

This is now driving me insane now! I want to animate an element 'left' using a - margin. But I'd also like to animate the same element in the opposite direction once all child elements have been shown. My script is not as simple but similar:

```
timer = setInterval(function(){
    var direction = ($('ul','.column').css('margin-left') <= 0)? '-=': '+=';
    $('ul','.column').animate({marginLeft:direction+($('li','.column').width())+'px'},500);
},1000);
```

I have also tried `$('ul,'.column').position().left <=0` instead of the condition above. My problem is `margin-left` and `position().left` never return a negative variable :S. If the variable 'should' be negative it's always returned as 0. I can easily work out the position of where I would want the animation to go in the opposite direction but again if the condition isn't a negative number this wont work.

I would much appreciate some insight to why `margin-left` and `position().left` always returns as 0 rather than -1000 or whatever. But if you have an alternative solution I'd still be as happy :)

Comment: P.S you don't need any more the 'px' if you use an updated jQuery lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's CSS margin-left will return a string like : `20px` you need to get rid of the 'px' using

```
parseInt( $('ul','.column').css('margin-left') , 10 )
```

So it should be:

```
timer = setInterval(function(){
    var margLeft = parseInt( $('ul','.column').css('margin-left') , 10);
    var direction =  margLeft<=0 ? '-=': '+=';
    $('ul','.column').animate({ marginLeft: direction+($('li','.column').width()) },500);
},1000);
```

And if I remember well Chrome has an issue to animate elements that have not specified inside the CSS the property to apply the animation, which means: make sure to set a value in your stylesheet for the element's margin-left you plan to animate.

Comment: @Beneto Next time don't drive crazy and come here earlier. *"Not to know is no shame. Shame is not to ask."* :)